# How do I use a QR code result from ZXing as a string?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I got [ZXing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode_Scanner_%28application%29) working using an intent, but I am really confused as how to use the output and save it as a string.

Here is the intent:

```
public void scan(View view) {

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); // "PRODUCT_MODE for bar codes

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
        startActivity(marketIntent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            //handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

And trying to use it as a string:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/"title_activity_on_activity_result"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />
```

And finally the strings:

```
<string name="app_name">TEST123</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="button_scan">Scan</string>
<string name="title_activity_activity_result">ActivityResult</string>
<string name="title_activity_on_activity_result">onActivityResult</string>
```

Exception:

```
EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
{com.JunkerDev.testfaggot/com.JunkerDev.testfaggot.MainActivity}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0,
result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has
extras) }} to activity
{com.JunkerDev.testfaggot/com.JunkerDev.testfaggot.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The text in the QR code is in the local variable `contents`. This has to be set as the text of your `TextView` with id `result`; In code, not in XML.

To do so, you should declare a member in your Activity:

```
TextView mResult;
```

In `onCreate()`, after `setContentView()`, bind it to the `TextView`:

```
mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
```

And finally in `onActivityResult()`:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    mResult.setText(contents);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, especially when you go into detail, but i still have a problem, now when i have scanned the qr code and it tries to go back (to hopefully showcase it in the textView) it crashes.

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace of the exception? You can find it in the LogCat window in red text

Comment: Kind of confused where to find the "trace of the exception" and google didn't have any immediate answer. Is that just logcat because for me that's filled up with like millions of messages every second.

Comment: In the LogCat select in the small menu "Error", so you see only the red text, and filter out the rest. The stack trace is a trace of what your app was doing when an exception was risen and it crashed

Comment: think i found it: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.JunkerDev.testfaggot/com.JunkerDev.testfaggot.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)

Comment: Yes, that's it. Now edit your original post and the complete message in it. Comments have size restrictions.

Comment: Just added it to the original post

Comment: Man i could really use some help, should be posted correctly

Comment: Good, but I guessed there was more text. The problem is a NullPointerException, it means some variable/reference was null when you tried to call a method on it. In the complete message there is the line number referencing where your code crashed. You can even double click on it to jump exactly there. Please post the rest of the message

Comment: it looks like it's this line of code: mResult.setText(contents); causing the nullpointecxeption

Comment: Are you still up for helping me or should i post a new thread?

Comment: Do not post a new thread. Did you add the line `mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);` in `onCreate()` after `setContentView(...)`? Has your TextView got the line `android:id="@+id/result"`?